# My Hawaii "Safe Travels" COVID test is still stuck in "Verification in Process". Is this a problem?

Tags: covid-19, hawaii

Hawaii now requires people to upload a recent COVID test to their [Safe Travels portal](https://travel.hawaii.gov/#/) to avoid a 10-day quarantine on arrival. I've uploaded mine on schedule, but its still stuck at "Verification In Process" on the day of the flight. Is this a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, its not a problem. I've arrived in Hawaii with a "Verification in Process" test and was allowed to exit the airport without issues. From speaking to other people who have recently traveled to Hawaii, this is normal - they probably verify the test, but fail to update the portal with the right status.